# Perform .join on a complex object with array of object dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a complex js object, that contains arrays of an object. The problem is some of the main object properties' arrays can have a different property.

```
var foo = {};
    foo.prop1 = [
                {name:"test", skill:1},
                {name:"test2", skill:2},
                ];
   foo.prop2 = [
                 {address:"Earth",distance:1},
                 {address:"Mars", distance:2}
                ]
```

My aim is to just replace the main object property value with the joined values for retrieval. 
This is what I have right now.

```
if(Object.keys(foo).length){
   Object.keys(foo).forEach(key => {

   var x = foo[key];
   if(key === "address") {
         foo[key] = x.map(function(elem){return elem.address;}).join(";");
   } else {
         foo[key] = x.map(function(elem){return elem.name;}).join(";");
   }

   });
  }
```

How can I make it dynamic so that I don't need to use the if statement? I just want to join all the first property of the inner obj.

Result:

```
foo new values would be: 
foo.prop1 = test;test2
foo.prop2 = Earth;Mars
```

I got it. I just want to join the first property of the sub object.

I replaced the if with this

```
foo[key] = x.map(function(elem){return elem[Object.keys(elem)[0]]; }).join(";");
```

Comment: An example of your desired result would help a lot

Comment: Short answer: you can't. The problem is that 'the first property of an object' can't be determined precisely, as object properties are not ordered. You can use a map if you want an *ordered* key-value structure.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to choose the value with string type

```
  var foo = {};
  foo.prop1 = [{
      name: "test",
      skill: 1
    },
    {
      name: "test2",
      skill: 2
    },
  ];
  foo.prop2 = [{
      address: "Earth",
      distance: 1
    },
    {
      address: "Mars",
      distance: 2
    }
  ]

  function formulate() {
    const result = {};
    (Object.keys(foo) || []).forEach(function(k) {
      result[k] = foo[k].map(function(val) {
        str_key = Object.keys(val).filter(function(val_k) {
          return typeof val[val_k] === "string";
        });
        return str_key.map(function(s) {
          return val[s];
        });
      }).join(";");
    });
    return result;
  }

  result = formulate()
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: I just want to join the first property of the sub object. I will try this too but I think I got the solution.

Comment: in a Javascript object, you cannot be sure about the first property. it can be `{address: "Earth", distance: 1}` or `{distance: 1, address: "Earth"}`. Both are considered to be the same

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this will work for you

```js
var foo = {};
    foo.prop1 = [
                {name:"test", skill:1},
                {name:"test2", skill:2},
                ];
   foo.prop2 = [
                 {address:"Earth",distance:1},
                 {address:"Mars", distance:2}
                ]


Object.keys(foo).forEach(key => {
 foo[key]=foo[key].map(val => { return Object.entries(val)[0][1] } ).toString().split(",").join(";")
});

console.log(foo)
```